# Is there a correct result when transforming XML to a table

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

When I ask what is 2+2, the correct answer is 4, no matter the intended use of that result.
Suppose I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<suite>
  <testcase id="001" kind="bvt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>4</arg1>
      <arg2>7</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>11.00</expected>
  </testcase>
  <testcase id="002" kind="drt">
    <inputs>
      <arg1>9</arg1>
      <arg2>6</arg2>
    </inputs>
    <expected>15.00</expected>
  </testcase>
</suite>
```

I have a tool/program that renders that as:

```
id kind arg1 arg2 expected
1  bvt  4    7    11
2  drt  9    6    15
```

I have another tool/program that renders that as:

```
testcase_id kind field value
001         bvt  arg1  4
001         bvt  arg2  7
001         bvt  expected 11.00
002         drt  arg1  9
002         drt  arg2  6
002         drt  expected 15.00
```

Again, in the spirit of 2+2=4, is there a correct answer? Are either of the above "correct"? If not, what is correct?

Answer (score 1):

***Correct*** requires a framework of constraints to reduce the space of possibilities. Underspecify the constraints, and you naturally can get *multiple **correct** answers*.

Without specifying further constraints, *of course* there are many possible transformations of XML into tabular form.

BTW, there are also many possible answers to `2 + 2`: 4, *4*, **4**, ***4***, four, FOUR, 3 + 1, 5 - 1, 22, ...

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes ... when you say "of course there are many possible transformations of XML into tabular form", how do you know this?

Comment: Because as the answer explains, the problem is underconstrained.  Further, the notion of mapping from a hierarchy to a table is fundamentally problematic in the first place.  You can make tradeoffs to tame the differences between the two data structures, but undefined notions of correctness are unhelpful.